# Adding Calculation to a lambda or function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have a df such as

```
    ID |    Status   | Color
   555    Cancelled     Green
   434    Processed     Red   
   212    Cancelled     Blue
   121    Cancelled     Green
   242    Cancelled     Blue
   352    Processed     Green
   343    Processed     Blue
```

I am using code such as below:

```
cc = df.groupby(by='Color').ID.count()
df.groupby(by=['Color', 'Status']).apply(lambda x: len(x)/cc.loc[x.Color.iloc[0]])
```

This gives me output such as

```
Color     Status   
Blue   Cancelled    0.666667
       Processed    0.333333
Green  Cancelled    0.666667
       Processed    0.333333
Red    Processed    1.000000
dtype: float64
```

Which gives me percentage of the status of each color.

There is also a field called **dollar_value** where each row contains dollar amounts, if I want to add two fields to my output of **1.** **Total_Dollars** for that color and status and **2.** the **dollar_per_order** for that color ( meaning if the Total_Dollars is 1000 and there are 200 rows for that color and status it would be 1000/200 or 5. Can I easily add both of these calculations to my output that I already have? Or would I need to create a function?

Desired Output:

```
    Color     Status              Total |Dollar_Per_Order                
    Blue   Cancelled    0.666667  1000       20
           Processed    0.333333  200        5
    Green  Cancelled    0.666667  2000       20
           Processed    0.333333  1000       5
    Red    Processed    1.000000  300        10
    dtype: float64
```

Thanks!

Comment: where is dollar value coming from??

Comment: `total_dolar` = `groupby().sum()`, `dolar_per_order` = `groupby().mean()`?

Comment: There is another column in the df with just dollar values for each row

Answer (score 1):

To compute all 3 columns, define a function to be applied to each group as:

```
def fn(grp):
    total = grp.dollar_value.sum()
    rowNo = len(grp.index)
    return pd.Series([ rowNo/cc[grp.name[0]], total, total/rowNo ],
        index=[ 'Percentage', 'Total_Dollars', 'Dollar_per_order'])
```

Then apply it:

```
df.groupby(by=['Color', 'Status']).apply(fn)
```

Note that I used `len(grp.index)` instead of `len(grp)`.
The reason is that it runs a little quicker.

I also read the *Color* of the current group other way than you.